# Need help fixing Javascript execution flow. Console.log is being revalidated upon opening

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

Alright, I have got the following 3 functions which help me collect Spotify genres based on Artists ID's. Since most tracks on Spotify have multiple Artists, I need to combine all the individual artists genres so that I can use them at a later point.

I have the following 3 functions:

```
const getArtist = async (artistId) => {
  console.log('4');
  const artistObject = await getData(
    'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/' + artistId
  ).then((artistObject) => {
    return artistObject;
  });
};
```

```
const getAllGenres = (artists) => {
  let artistGenres = [];
  console.log('2');

  artists.map(async (item) => {
    console.log('3');
    await getArtist(item.id).then(async (artist) => {
      console.log('5');
      await artist.genres.map((genre) => {
        if (artistGenres.indexOf(genre) == -1) {
          artistGenres.push(genre);
        }
      });
    });
  });

  return artistGenres;
};
```

And

```
const getGenre = (artists) => {
  console.log('1');
  const allgenres = getAllGenres(artists);

  console.log('6', allgenres);
}
```

Whenever I check the value of `allgenres` in the console it looks empty but whenever I click the arrow to unfold it, it has value. I know that this is because it revalidates the value of `allgenres` whenever I unfold the array.

I have looked online for solutions regarding this and came across async/await. I have tried this and had to change `getAllGenres` into a promise. Not a problem but it did not solve the issue.

I have added some console.logs to help me understand the current flow of execution:

```
1
2
3
4
3
4
6 [] <- Revalidates after opening
5
5
```

From my understanding console.log(6) should be the last to be executed but this is not the case.

Comment: You might find it easier to understand if you didn't mix `async/await` with `then` callbacks.

Comment: @Andy Thanks for your input. I went ahead and removed all the `.then` callbacks and am only using `async/await`. I fail to see what exactly is causing this behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have been suggested, do not mix `then` and `async/await` syntax, since you make the code harder to read, I can't test the code since I don't have access to that api, but this should work:

```
const getArtist = (artistId) => {
  return getData('https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/' + artistId);
};

const getAllGenres = async (artists) => {
  let artistGenres = [];
  await Promise.all(
    artists.map(async (item) => {
      const artist = await getArtist(item.id);
      artist.genres.forEach((genre) => {
        if (artistGenres.indexOf(genre) == -1) {
          artistGenres.push(genre);
        }
      });
    })
  );
  return artistGenres;
};

const getGenre = async (artists) => {
  const allgenres = await getAllGenres(artists);
  console.log(allgenres);
};
```

1. `getArtist` doesn't need to be async since `getData` must be an async function that returns a promise, so getArtist will return a promise automatically.
2. `getGenre` on the other hand, must be async, since you need to wat to retrieve all the genres before using them, and that happens asynchronously.
3. `getAllGenres` is where you have to be careful, you are going to throw several async calls in parallel, that's a scenario you need to handle with `Promise.all`, you find a lot of resource here on SO on this specific subject.

Comment: Instead of having a separate array I would return `artists.map` from the function, and then use `await Promise.all` in the main function.

Comment: Ah okey, I see. So basically what the Promise.all does in this example is tell the code to wait for all the artists.map itterations to finish?

Comment: Yeah, so `map` builds up an array of promises, and [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) waits for them all to resolve (or not). There's also [`Promise.allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) now too which is slightly different.

Comment: @Andy I think it's better hiding the implementation details of the API that you directly expose,  this way `getAllGenres` is easy to use by anyone that has no idea about what it does internally. 
Promise.all() takes an array of promises ( you create one doing .map with an async callback, since async functions return promises ) and returns a single promise that resolves when all of the promises have oassed from pending to fulfilled and rejects if only one of the promises rejects. So you can just await for it as you do with any other promise.

Comment: Alright, thanks guys. Appreciate the help.